# Making grub boot into chroot directory

Tags: linux, boot, grub, slackware

I am trying to make grub boot into a chroot directory /slack containing a Slackware Linux installation. This directory was created by issuing the following command:

```
  installpkg --root /slack a/*.t?z
```

where a/ directory contains the basic a/ instalation packages from slackware. I sucessfully chrooted into /slack and created the initrd image, by executing mkinitcpio command.

Finally, I created the following entry in /boot/grub/menu.lst:

```
title  Slackware Linux
root   (hd0,2)
kernel /slack/boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda3 rw init=/slack/boot/chrootinit 
initrd /slack/boot/initrd.gz
boot
```

where /slack/boot/chrootinit is a script that chroots into /slack:

```
exec /usr/sbin/chroot /slack /sbin/init
```

The system boots sucessfully but even with the "rw" option, the root partition is mounted as readonly. Several warning messages about this problem are displayed and the system finally hangs. Any solutions?

(REF: http://forum.soft32.com/linux2/Booting-chrooted-directory-ftopict51395.html)